# Android Delay in Picture Appearing in Custom Folder

Tags: android, image, save, directory, delay

In my app, I use the built in camera to take a picture and then I store it in my own custom folder.  For whatever reason, my image takes a long time to display in my custom folder and I can't figure out how to speed up the process.  I have done a good amount of research, but it seems that most of the problems are more of the image never displaying, when mine does display, just after a very long delay.  Are there any ideas out there?  Below is my code where I create, name and save the image that is taken.  Thank you!

```
i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                 String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myDir = new File(root + "/MyCustomFolder/");    
                        myDir.mkdirs();
                        if (myDir.exists()) {

                        }
                        Random generator = new Random(); 
                        int n = 10000;
                        n = generator.nextInt(n);
                        String fname = "CustomImage-"+ n +".jpg";

                        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file); 
                        i.putExtra("output", uriSavedImage);

                            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/MyCustomFolder/");
                                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                                    Uri.parse("file://"+ mediaStorageDir)));


                startActivityForResult(i, cameraData); 
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!  Simply remove the

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/MyCustomFolder/");
```

and I was golden!